# How can I safely copy collections?

Tags: java, collections, copy-constructor

In the past, I've said to safely copy a collection do something like:

```
public static void doThing(List<String> strs) {
    List<String> newStrs = new ArrayList<>(strs);
```

or

```
public static void doThing(NavigableSet<String> strs) {
    NavigableSet<String> newStrs = new TreeSet<>(strs);
```

But are these "copy" constructors, similar static creation methods and streams, *really* safe and where are the rules specified? By safe I mean are the basic *semantic integrity* guarantees offered by the Java language and collections enforced against a malicious caller, assuming backed up by a reasonable `SecurityManager` and that there are no flaws.

I'm happy with the method throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`, `NullPointerException`, `IllegalArgumentException`, `ClassCastException`, etc., or perhaps even hanging.

I have chosen `String` as an example of an immutable type argument. For this question, I'm not interested in deep copies for collections of mutable types which has its own gotchas.

(To be clear, I have looked at the OpenJDK source code and have some kind of answer for [`ArrayList`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk14/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L181) and [`TreeSet`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk14/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/TreeSet.java#L172).)

Comment: What do you mean by *safe*? Generally speaking the classes in the collections framework tend to work similarly, with exceptions specified in the javadocs. The copy constructors are just as "safe" as any other constructors. Is there a particular thing you have in mind, because asking whether a collection copy constructor is safe sounds very specific?

Comment: @Kayaman I mean is the new collection guaranteed to behave as it should do. As if I had added my own `String`s myself. Like 3GL languages and libraries should (not C and C++).

Comment: Are you asking whether an ArrayList honors the contract of List, and whether a TreeSet honors the contract of NavigableSet?

Comment: @VGR I am specifically asking about the case of using the copy constructors with untrusted arguments. But more generally to include collections other than `ArrayList` and `TreeSet`.

Comment: I would say it’s safe, as long as the argument honors the contract of List/Set, which it very likely does.  Unless someone did something crazy like implementing List directly.  I do defensive copies this way all the time.

Comment: Well, `NavigableSet` and other `Comparable` based collections can sometimes detect if a class doesn't implement `compareTo()` correctly and throw an exception. It's a bit unclear what you mean by untrusted arguments. You mean an evildoer crafts a collection of bad Strings and when you copy them to your collection something bad happens? No, the collections framework is pretty solid, it's been around since 1.2.

Comment: You could check for the actual (Runtime) class of the passed List and whitelist a few (for example whitelist ArrayList, LinkedList and a few more that you mark as "trusted"). Then, of course, make sure the classes were loaded by a trusted ClassLoader

Comment: @codeflush.dev That isn't what the static type of any reasonable interface says, and I don't want to add any natural language preconditions. I just want a copy.

Comment: @codeflush.dev Oh, and of course, if even a copy with a specified type can remain compromised, how do we know a copy with a specified type of a specified type instance is safe?

Comment: Could you please clarify what a malicious caller is? Is that an untrusted implementation of Collection?

Comment: @JesseWilson In this case it could be an untrusted implementation of the collection argument, but also a trusted collection could have been compromised by the caller - perhaps playing with it's internals or modifying it from a different thread. However, I wouldn't want to exclude any legitimate implementation and incompetence is a much more common (near universal) problem than maliciousness even in 2020.

Comment: @JesseWilson you can compromise a lot of the standard collections without hacking into their internals, `HashSet` (and all other hashing collections in general) relies on the correctness/integrity of the `hashCode` implementation of the elements, `TreeSet` and `PriorityQueue` depend on the `Comparator` (and you can’t even create an equivalent copy without accepting the custom comparator if there is one), `EnumSet` trusts the integrity of the particular `enum` type which is never verified after compilation, so a class file, not generated with `javac` or handcrafted, can subvert it.

Comment: @Holger I think you want to distinguish between hacking the internals of the collection and the elements misimplementing their interface, although their is some crossover. *Typically,* you are going validate each element before using it, and one doesn't appear that's just the same as it not being in the collection (with qualifications). I think the *bulk shallow collection copy* is unique in the Oracle Java secure coding guidelines in that it doesn't really cause problems (although it does in discussions of real problems). Copying arrays has come up.

Comment: In your examples, you have `new TreeSet<>(strs)` where `strs` is a `NavigableSet`. This isn’t a bulk copy, as the resulting `TreeSet` will use the source’s comparator, which is even necessary to retain the semantics. If you are fine with just processing the contained elements, `toArray()` is the way to go; it will even keep the iteration order. When you are fine with “take element, validate element, use element”, you don’t even need to make a copy. The problems start when you want to verify all elements, followed by using all elements. Then, you can’t trust a `TreeSet` copy w custom comparator

Comment: @Holger By *bulk copy* what I intend to mean is that "our" code is doing the copy as one call. The relevance is that if elements copied one by one, there is an implicit `checkcast` in there. They will definitely be `String`s and not something else. You'd probably wnat to check they aren't `null` anyway at some point - you could delay to immediate prior to use..

Comment: The only bulk copy operation having the effect of a `checkcast` for each element, is `toArray` with a specific type. We are always ending at it. The generic collections do not even know their actual element type, so their copy constructors can't provide a similar functionality. Of course, you can defer any check to right prior use, but then, I don't know what your questions is aiming at. You don't need "semantic integrity", when you are fine with checking and failing immediately before using elements.

Answer (score 12):

There’s no real protection against intentionally malicious code running within the same JVM in ordinary APIs, like the Collection API.

As can easily be demonstrated:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Object[] array = { "foo", "bar", "baz", "and", "another", "string" };
    array[array.length - 1] = new Object() {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));
            return "string";
        }
    };
    doThing(new ArrayList<String>() {
        @Override public Object[] toArray() {
            return array;
        }
    });
}

public static void doThing(List<String> strs) {
    List<String> newStrs = new ArrayList<>(strs);

    System.out.println("made a safe copy " + newStrs);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(newStrs);
    }
}
```

```
made a safe copy [foo, bar, baz, and, another, string]
[bar, and, string, string, another, foo]
[and, baz, bar, string, string, string]
[another, baz, and, foo, bar, string]
[another, bar, and, foo, string, and]
[another, baz, string, another, and, foo]
[string, and, another, foo, string, foo]
[baz, string, foo, and, baz, string]
[bar, another, string, and, another, baz]
[bar, string, foo, string, baz, and]
[bar, string, bar, another, and, foo]
```

As you can see, expecting a `List<String>` doesn’t guaranty to actually get a list of `String` instances. Due to type erasure and raw types, there isn’t even a fix possible on the list implementation side.

The other thing, you can blame `ArrayList`’s constructor for, is the trust in the incoming collection’s `toArray` implementation. `TreeMap` isn’t affected in the same way, but only because there is no such performance gain from passing the array, as in the construction of an `ArrayList`. Neither class guarantees a protection in the constructor.

Normally, there is no point in trying to write code assuming intentionally malicious code around every corner. There’s too much it can do, to protect against everything. Such protection is only useful for code which does really encapsulate an action which could give a malicious caller access to something, it couldn’t already access without this code.

If you need safety for a particular code, use

```
public static void doThing(List<String> strs) {
    String[] content = strs.toArray(new String[0]);
    List<String> newStrs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(content));

    System.out.println("made a safe copy " + newStrs);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(newStrs);
    }
}
```

Then, you can be sure that `newStrs` does only contain strings and can’t get modified by other code after its construction.

Or use `List<String> newStrs = List.of(strs.toArray(new String[0]));` with Java 9 or newer
Note that Java 10’s `List.copyOf(strs)` does the same, but its documentation doesn’t state that it is guaranteed not to trust the incoming collection’s `toArray` method. So calling `List.of(…)`, which will definitely make a copy in case it returns an array based list, is safer.

Since no caller can alter the way, arrays work, dumping the incoming collection into an array, followed by populating the new collection with it, will always make the copy safe. Since the collection can hold a reference to the returned array as demonstrated above, it could alter it during the copy phase, but it can’t affect the copy in the collection.

So any consistency checks should be done after the particular element has been retrieved from the array or on the resulting collection as a whole.

Comment: I accept some of what you say somewhere in there, but: "There’s no real protection against intentionally malicious code running within the same JVM." Then how do old school applets work (to the extent they do)? The code presented only works as it does because you don't get the individual elements out, which you'd need to for anything useful. Change the loop to: `for(int i = 0; i < newStrs.size(); i++) { System.out.println(newStrs.get(i)); }` and you get a CCE (perhaps not very early releases of Java 1.5) at least eventually.

Comment: Java’s security model works by granting code the intersection of the permission sets of all code on the stack, so when the caller of your code makes your code do unintended things, it still doesn’t get more permissions than it initially had. So it only makes your code do things the malicious code could have done without your code as well. You only have to harden the code you intent to run with elevated privileges via `AccessController.doPrivileged(…)` etc. But the long list of applet security related bugs gives us a hint why this technology has been abandoned…

Comment: But I should have inserted “in ordinary APIs like the Collection API”, as that’s what I was focusing on in the answer.

Comment: I don't think that's entirely true.

Comment: Other than it's not just about security (the thing I most liked about Java coming from C++ was the trustworthiness), it's a bit long for a comment. If our code is ever used by something privileged (we can't say that it wont be in future) it needs to be "hardened" (we are in the middle of this transitive relationship), or if it uses something that does *or has been obtained* from something that is privileged (which is essentially everything). Privilege may come from caller sensitive methods, native code or access to statics.

Comment: Why should you harden your code, which apparently isn’t security relevant, against privileged code which does allow a malicious collection implementation slip in? That hypothetical caller would still be subject to the malicious behavior before and after calling your code. It wouldn’t even notice that your code is the only one behaving correctly. Using `new ArrayList<>(…)` as copy constructor is fine assuming correct collection implementations. It’s not your duty to fix security issues when it is already too late. What about compromised hardware? The operating system? How about multi-threading?

Comment: Even in the Java Library there are many collections that do not correctly implement their supertypes. We copy arguments so that our class behaviour keeps its head when all about classes are losing theirs and blaming it on our class. It ought to actually do that. I would like to delegate copying of a collection to the `ArrayList` constructor, so we should also be able to take on delegation. It is literally true that it was not my duty to fix security issues - I had to delegate that and bash my head against the wall. You seem to be advocating no security and indeed no semantic integrity ever ...

Comment: I’m not advocating “no security”, but security at the right places, instead of trying to fix a broken environment after the fact. It’s an interesting claim that “*there are many collections that do not correctly implement their supertypes*” but it went too far already, to ask for proves, expanding this even further. The original question has been answered completely; the points you are bringing now were never part of it. As said, `List.copyOf(strs)` does not rely on the incoming collection’s correctness in that regard, at the obvious price. `ArrayList` is a reasonable-for-everyday compromise.

Comment: I don't think it answers the "similar static creation methods and streams, really safe and where are the rules specified?" part of the question. For instance I don't see a material difference in the API docs for `copyOf` and the `ArrayList` "copy constructor". All I can do is to the look at the source code of a particular version in unfeasible detail for each method/constructor, and hope nothing changes - unless there is documentation.

Comment: It clearly says that there is no such specification, for all “similar static creation methods and streams”. So if you want to absolutely safe, you have to call `toArray()` yourself, because arrays can’t have overridden behavior, followed by creating a collection copy of the array, like `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( strs.toArray(new String[0])))` or `List.of(strs.toArray(new String[0]))`. Both also have the side effect of enforcing the element type. I, personally, don’t think they will ever allow `copyOf` to compromise the immutable collections, but the alternatives are there, in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather left this information in comment, but i don't have enough reputation, sorry :) I'll try to explain it as much verbose as I can then.

Instead of something like `const` modifier used in C++ to mark member functions which are not supposed to modify object contents, in Java originally was used concept of "immutability". Encapsulation (or OCP, Open-Closed Principle) was supposed to protect against any unexpected mutations (changes) of an object. Of course reflection API walks this around; direct memory access does the same; that's more about shooting own leg :)

`java.util.Collection` itself is mutable interface: it has `add` method which is supposed to modify collection. Of course programmer may wrap collection into something which will throw... and all the runtime exceptions will happen because another programmer was not able to read javadoc which clearly says that collection is immutable.

I decided to use `java.util.Iterable` type to expose immutable collection in my interfaces. Semantically `Iterable` does not have such characteristic of collection as "mutability". Still you will (most probably) be able to modify underlying collections through streams.

---

JIC, to expose maps in immutable manner `java.util.Function<K,V>` can be used (map's `get` method fits this definition)

Comment: The concepts of read-only interfaces and immutability are orthogonal.

The point of C++ and C is that they don't support *semantic integrity*. The also copy object/struct arguments - const & is a dodgy optimisation for that.

If you were to pass an `Iterator` then that practically forces an elementwise copy, but that isn't nice. Using `forEachRemaining`/`forEach` is obviously going to be a complete disaster. (I also have to mention that `Iterator` has a `remove` method.)

Comment: If look at Scala collections library there is strict distinction between mutable and immutable interfaces. Though (I suppose) it was made so because of completely different reasons, but still is a demonstration of how safety can be achieved. Read-only interface *semantically* assumes immutability, that's what I'm trying to say. (I agree regarding `Iterable`'s not being actually immutable, but don't see any issues with `forEach*`)